# Reset an input select on other select value

Tags: jquery, reset

I've 2 select inputs and im trying to reset the 2nd one depends on the 1st value but i cant figure it out..

The showing&hiding part are working well but i really cant reset the 2nd select

Here's the HTML part :

```
 <div>
   <select id="select_cat" name="cat">
    <option value>Choose a cat</option>
    <option value ="cat1">cat 1</option>
    <option value ="cat2">cat 2</option>
    <option value ="cat3">cat 3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="div_sub_cat">
  <select id="select_sub_cat" name="sub_cat">
    <option value>Choose a sub cat</option>
    <option value ="sub_cat1">sub_cat 1</option>
    <option value ="sub_cat2">sub_cat 2</option>
    <option value ="sub_cat3">sub_cat 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here's the jquery part :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#div_sub_cat').hide();

   /**
   * the select_sub_cat should select the default option everytime it shows
   */
   $('#select_cat').change(function(){
    if($('#select_cat option:selected').text() == 'cat 2') {
        $('#div_sub_cat').show('fast'); 
        $('select#select_sub_cat').val('').prop('selected', true);
    } else {
        $('#div_sub_cat').hide('fast'); 
    } 
   });
 });
```

I tried various way to do it such as :

```
 if($('#select_type option:selected').text() == 'cat 2') {
    $('#div_sub_cat').show('fast'); 

    //what ive already tried
    $('#select_sub_cat').val('');
    //i tried to select an other option but didnt work too..
    $('#select_sub_cat option[value="sub_cat2"]')
 }
```

I really cant see what imma doing wrong ! Any ideas ?

**EDIT**
The best answer for me was Qsprec's but ssilas777's is working too if you want to select a specific option

Comment: Did you tried: $('#select_sub_cat').val(0);

Comment: Yeah working great !

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if($('#select_type option:selected').text() == 'cat 2') {
    $('#div_sub_cat').show('fast'); 
    $('select#select_sub_cat').val("sub_cat2");
}
```